# In the triangle $ABC$,if median through $A$ is inclined at $45^\circ$ with the side $BC$ and $C=30^\circ$,then $B$ can be

Tags: geometry

In the triangle $ABC$,if median through $A$ is inclined at $45^\circ$ with the side $BC$ and $C=30^\circ$,then $B$ can be equal to
$(A)15^\circ\hspace{1cm}(B)75^\circ\hspace{1cm}(C)115^\circ\hspace{1cm}(D)135^\circ$

---

Let AD be the median.Angle $ADC=45^\circ,ACD=30^\circ,CAD=105^\circ$.and $BD=CD$
Then i am stuck,how to find angle $B?$Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: I think the wording does not necessarily suggest $\angle ADC=45^\circ$. Could it be $\angle ADC=135^\circ$?

Comment: @Element118, what you stated in the above comment may be true, But, I think the order in which $BC$ is written is important. OP could tell that "inclined with the side $CB$", then your result was true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is way to compute the angle $\angle BAD$ using the rule of sines where $D$ is mid point of $BC.$
let me use $t = \angle BAD.$

suing the rule of sin on $\Delta ABD, \Delta ADC$  we have $$\frac{BD}{\sin t} = \frac{AD}{\sin(t + 45^\circ)}, \frac{CD}{\sin(15^\circ)} = \frac{AD}{\sin 30^\circ} $$ 
from the two equations, we get $$\frac{AD}{BD} = \frac{sin(t+45^\circ)}{\sin t}=\frac{\sin 30^\circ}{\sin 15^\circ}=2\cos 15^\circ \to \tan t =\frac 1{2\sqrt 2 \cos 15^\circ - 1}  = \frac 1 {\sqrt 3}. $$

therefore $t = 30^\circ, \angle B = 105^\circ$

Comment: Great answer in principle, but I think you have $AD$ leaning in the wrong direction.  105 is not one of the possible answers.

Comment: If we take the angle $ADC$ and use the method suggested above by @abel,then we get angle $B=15^\circ$,which is one of the options.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing a straightforward way to calculate $B$.  However, this is multiple choice, and you can eliminate the impossible values, leaving the correct one.  Ask yourself: Given what you know, what is the largest $B$ could possibly be?

UPDATE: This works is $\angle ADC=45$, not $\angle ADB=45$.  Apparently there is some confusion about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Geogebra you can easily find the answer yourself:

[image]

Now we you only need to prove it. :)

---

Edit: It seems that the inclination of the median is not clear, but making the two choices on the same figure brings an immediate solution:

In triangle $AED$ we have $\frac{EC}{DC} = \frac{\sin 45^\circ}{\sin 105^\circ}=\sqrt{3}-1$. In triangle $ADC$ we have $\frac{DC}{AC} = \frac{\sin 15^\circ}{\sin 135^\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}$

This means that $\frac{2DC}{AC} = \frac{EC}{DC}$ so $DC \cdot BC = AC \cdot EC$. Thus $A,B,D,E$ are on the same circle and $\angle ABC = 105^\circ$ and $\angle EBC = \angle EAD = 15^\circ$.

So the right position of $A$ is in fact the position of $E$ in the second figure, and $\angle B = 15^\circ$.

I used freely the well known facts: $\sin 15^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$ and $\sin 105^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}$. These can be deduced immediately using formulas for $\sin(a\pm b)$.

[image]

Comment: Well, this has already been discussed, but I interpreted the question s.t. $\angle ADC$ is 45.  Changes things completely.  Maybe we need some clarity on this?

Comment: Since $B=105°$ is not one of the choices and  $\angle ADC=45°$ yields exactly one possible answer, I guess @bob.sacamento is right and Beni Bogosel is wrong here. (Depends on the nature of the multiple choice test and if "no choice" is allowed.)

Answer (score 0):

Way late, but here's a geometric solution.
[image]
Let $D$ be the midpoint of $\overline {BC}$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of       $\overline{AC}$ and let $E$ be the foot of the altitude through $A$.

Assume $\angle ADC=45$. Then $DE=AE$ since $\triangle AED$ is right. Since  $\triangle     AEC$ is right with $\angle ACE=30$, deduce $AE=\frac12 AC$. Since $M$ is a midpoint, we know $\frac12       AC=MC$. But $\triangle EMC$ is isosceles with $MC=ME$.

This shows that $DE=ME$, so $\triangle DEM$ is isosceles. Then $\angle MDE$ is half of the exterior angle $\angle MEC$, which equals $30$ since$ \triangle EMC$ is  isosceles. So $\angle MDE=15$.

Finally, $D$ and $M$ are midpoints, so $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle    MDC$.
Conclude $\angle ABC=\angle MDC=15$.

(This question is solved by the same triangle as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1819672/215011), hence the same diagram and similar line of reasoning.)